# Ограничение выполнения скрипта по времени

Tags: php

Как можно реализовать скрипт, чтобы пользователь с одного IP не мог его выполнять чаще чем, например, 5 раз в 12 часов? Без использования сессий и куков?

Comment: Хранить в БД `IP` и данные по количеству запросов и времени между выполнениями.

Comment: Или использовать cache c той же информацией